# mvc routing generates iis 7.5 error forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I my WebApplication I have an ASPX WebForms Page here:

> ~/ASPWebforms/MyFolder/Default.aspx

If I use this code:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapPageRoute(
                    "SomeRoute",
                    "Test/{reportname}",
                    "~/ASPWebforms/MyFolder/{reportname}.aspx"
       );
```

and then enter this in the browser:

> localhost/MySite/Test/Default

**I get the desired the result: The page ~/ASPWebforms/MyFolder/Default.aspx is displayed.**

But if I use the following
 code

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
                    "SomeRoute",
                    "Test/",
                    "~/ASPWebforms/MyFolder/Default.aspx"
       );
```

and try

> localhost/MySite/Test

IIS 7.5 says:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

**Do I do something wrong in the last piece of code?**

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I had something a lot like this, and from reading around it seems like it could be caused by several different things. In my case I had a route like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("signin", "signin", "~/SignIn/SignIn.aspx")
```

So the route path is `/signin`, but there is also a folder called `/signin` containing the .aspx page.

I got the error response 
`HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory`.

This was fixed when I added this line to the route config:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

The error message has a grain of truth in it: `/signin` is a directory, and the web server is configured to not list files in it. It seems that this file path takes precedence over the route unless you configure it otherwise.

Other things that I tried:

- I did not need to use a different overload of `MapPageRoute`
- I did not need to add `UrlRoutingModule` to the web.config under
  `system.webServer|Modules`. It works without that.
- It works without the web.config setting 
  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`
  I do have that for other reasons, but if I remove it then this fix still works.
- I did install the server feature "Http Redirection" in the machine's `Server Manager|Web
  Server|Add Role Services` dialogue but after removing it again this still works.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall .NET 4 x86 & x64 on IIS 7.5 and setup your web site .net version.
I write simple commands by default x86.

Stopping IIS:
1)iisreset /stop

Stup command(for iis  by default .net stup):
2) cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
3)aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Reset command(for iis by defalt .net change to .net 4 version):
4)aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

Starting IIS:
5)iisreset /start

Comment: Thx for your answer! Unfortunately, this didn't do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the route using one of the overloads that sets default values like so:

```
            routes.MapPageRoute(
                    "SomeRoute",
                    "Test/{reportname}",
                    "~/ASPWebforms/MyFolder/{reportname}.aspx",
                    false,
                    new RouteValueDictionary(new {reportname = "Default"})
            );
```

Not massively confident it will sort your problem but with it working with your original example it could well do.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Unfortunately if I enter "localhost/MySite/Test" I still get "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden". And if I enter "localhost/MySite/Test/Default" I get the desired result.